# simple inquiry about variable modifiers in C

Tags: c, coding-style, standards

I've always thought I knew C well enough, but I've ALWAYS been unsure whether these two are **by standard** equivalent:

```
/* ========= */

const int i;
const int j;

/* as opposed to */

const int i, j;

/* ========= */
```

Whenever I just need to modify a couple of variables, I just use the 1st notation. I know these works both for GCC and MSVC,  but not having read the venerable "K&R", I don't know if this is by standard.

Comment: It's strictly the same thing.

Comment: Isn't it more about coding style than standards?

Comment: It may be faster to ask here, but it teaches you a lot less than finding out the answer on your own. You don't need to get a copy of K&R to do that (though it's probably searchable), just compile two simple sources to assembly and see what the compiler changes (which is simple since nothing of substance will be different).

Comment: @Mauren: Once you know the answer to this question, yes. Before that, not necessarily.

Comment: It may be faster to ask, but it's still rude to do so without performing your own research. _Your convenience should not by default come at the expense of ours._

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the following:

```
const int i;
const int j;
```

is equivalent to

```
const int i, j;
```

**But**, if those were meant to be pointer to int, then

```
const int* i, j;
```

isn't the same as:

```
const int* i;
const int* j;
```

but the latter two declarations are equivalent to:

```
const int *i, *j;
```

Comment: maybe this implies that it is better practice to attach the '\*' to the variable name instead of its type, e.g. int *i rather than int\* i. Makes the above issue slightly more intuitive to read and understand?

Comment: @Hiett Yes, or maybe create typedefs.

Comment: that said i note that K&R use int\* i rather than int \*i so who am i to argue ;-)

Comment: I have been using `int *i` and K&R never came to haunt me ;)

Comment: @Hiett K&R is completely worthless to use as a style guide. Why consult a dinosaur about how to write modern programs? Neither proper programming style nor proper program design was invented when dinosaurs roamed the earth.

Comment: @Danvil They better not!

Answer (score -1):

One can ascertain that these expressions are equivalent by compiling a simple test and looking at the assembly output.

```
main()
{
    const int i=1;
    const int j=2;
}
```

> gcc test.c -S -o output.s -O0

```
main()
{
    const int i=1, j=2;
}
```

The output for both is identical, something that looks like this. (Comments added by me).

```
main:
    #Set up the stack frame
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp

    #Make room on the stack for 2 local variables
    subl    $16, %esp

    #Assign the literal value of 1 to the first local variable
    movl    $1, -4(%ebp)

    #Assign the literal value of 2 to the second local variable
    movl    $2, -8(%ebp)

    leave
```

If you are wondering about no mention to "const", this is because const is merely a higher level construct in the C langauge.

Comment: But if you have `int* i; int* j;` and `int* i, j;`, the disassembly doesn't necessarily show any difference, in case pointers and ints have the same size.

Comment: This is just a syntax error. I thought the point of the question was about the literal difference between `int i; int j;` and `int i, j;` or `int *i; int *j;` and `int *i, *j;` which is what my answer addresses.

Comment: i was just writing a few macros that declares any number of variables passed to it, via variadics. i provided a "modifier" argument, then i actually started wondering what effect it would have for all other variable names passed as variadics.

Comment: Yes indeed that was the question. My point is that I don't think the assembly proves anything.

Comment: It can't prove your C syntax is correct C syntax no. It can prove that the resulting machine code does the same thing.

Comment: Checking for identical assembly code output is a poor test for anything in C. Consider two programs, one of which is legal C with no undefined behaviour, and the other of which has undefined behaviour. Since UB may by definition do anything, it may do the same thing as the legal program, and therefore may generate the same assembly code. Would you then conclude that both programs are well-defined because they have the same assembly code?